# AWS MediaLive for VOD to live

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live

I've successfully used MediaLive to stream from OBS to a custom website in the past. That was all well and good because it was essentially live to live. I'm now exploring the option of doing some pre-recorded content that I can playback at specific times. I was just wondering if anyone had any tips on the following workflow?

Pre-stream, the webpage will show a holding image in the player. About 1 minute before the actual content goes live, my plan is to "stream" that image and then at the exact time the stream should be live, to use a schedule action to switch inputs to an MP4 pull from S3.

This is essentially what YouTube premiere does, as far as I can tell.

Is there a better way to do VOD to live (within the AWS product range)? My only conern, is that MediaLive is slightly clunky.

Comment: This AWS Solution may be useful: https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/video-on-demand-on-aws/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question on stackoverflow, for your described workflow MediaLive would be the best option since you are looking to Live Stream Vod content.  The workflow you describe where you will use a scheduled action to switch inputs is exactly how I would configure it as well.  Here is a link for more information and limitations on input switching within medialive.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/scheduled-input-switching.html

Zach